# Onelogin SAML PHP toolkit - can it be used with a none onelogin SAML Identity Provider?

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

I am looking for a solution to implementing SAML authentication with in house ADFS and shibboleth Idp's (identity provider) .

Does anyone have experience of using onelogin php toolkit?

Is this library suitable or just for use with the onelogin SAML Idp?

https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml

It looks promising, the other option could be simpleSamlphp - but onelogin seems more adopted.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm the developer of OneLogin php toolkit.

You can use this toolkit in order to deploy a Service Provider and connect it with any Identity Provider.

As you can see, we provide a [demo](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/tree/master/demo1) with its [explanation](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml#demo1) that will teach you to use the toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need SAML SP (service provider) SSO, right? Haven't used onelogin, but though mature it looks archaic, and not PSR-0. I like http://www.lightsaml.com/. Though young in version 1.0 it's a next major version of [aerialship/lightsaml](https://packagist.org/packages/aerialship/lightsaml). LightSAML has much richer implementation of SAML data model object. It also supports Symfony and provides a security bundle. It only supports SAML v2, but as I know, both ADFS and shibboleth implement SAML v2, and I used it with both and it works like a charm.

Comment: php-saml is not PSR-4 (PSR-0 is deprecated) but why you say that it looks archaic? When I implemented it there was alternatives like lightsaml or simpleSAMLphp so I decided to implement it in a different way, and right now you can see that has huge adoption and a lot of plugins and frameworks adopted it. I invite you to use it in your next project and you will see how easy is.

Comment: Sure @smartin I'm pretty sure it works well for the scope of it's purpose, but it was quite a while back when php had no namespaces and PEAR class naming was used, and when there was no composer and including dependency libs in own repo was normal - those are the reasons I said "archaic", in means like it was done before. Afterall it's just my subjective opinion, please don't take it personally. Cheers

Comment: It's ok. maybe one day I release a new "less archaic version", but right now I'm focused on new releases of SAML toolkits on other languages and new functionality.

At the end, you can add this toolkit to your project at composer and only need to call the API methods that are enough flexible and simple to connect with any IdP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with **any** IDP (Identity Provider). Please read the [General Description](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml#general-description) section for details.